# How to return a function that returns a trait in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, closures, traits

My goal is to implement a function that returns another function, which returns some trait. To be more specific, the returned function should itself return a Future.

To return a function that returns a concrete type, we obviously can do this:

```rust
fn returns_closure() -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
    |x| x + 1
}
```

But what if instead of `i32` we want to return a `Future`?

I tried the following:

```rust
use futures::Future;

fn factory() -> (impl Fn() -> impl Future) {
    || async {
        // some async code
    }
}
```

This does not work because the second `impl` keyword is not allowed:

`` error[E0562] `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types ``

What is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=16aafcdd331d34d36ab894f8a5ae4562 ?

Comment: @Stargateur Isn't that a future returning a closure rather than a closure returning a future?

Comment: @SvenMarnach until async closure are stable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this on stable Rust. However, you can use a type alias for an **opaque type** (also known as existential type) on Rust nightly like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2ee7e49491d22949f739699b6e5946af)):

```
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

use futures::Future;

type Fut<O> = impl Future<Output = O>;

fn factory<O>() -> impl Fn() -> Fut<O> {
    || async {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like there isn't a good way to do this in stable Rust yet, unlike I missed something.